# He hasn’t worked for years?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

What does the sentence **'' He hasn't worked for years ''** actually tell us?

He hasn't worked for years. ( ... still doesn't work )

He hasn't worked for years. ( until now ) but now he will ?

Comment: Could be either, depends on context.

Comment: Alone, it is purely a statement about the past. As @StuartF says, additional meaning **may** be supplied by context (surrounding or nearby words), e.g. **He hasn't worked for years** _and isn't likely to start now / and doesn't need to because he wrote a best-selling novel when he was 20 / but is starting at Tesco next week_.

Comment: Or tone of voice: _Is he an industrious type of person? He hasn't worked for years!_ (said disparagingly).

Comment: you have explained it very nicely. As you say, it depends on the situation. I saw it as it is alone in a grammar book. in your first example there is a reference to the past tense and in the second there is a reference to the present tense. you are great. i started to grasp the subject slowly. i will open another topic like this. it seems that i will grasp it better then.

Comment: By the way, when I wrote to you I said "you have explained it very nicely." I think that is also a correct expression. I referred to the past, but I used that expression because it was an event that just happened.

Comment: @emilywenly  This might be too soon, but you don't need the have "you explained it very nicely" works as well. we sort of fill in the have. (there are many questions on here giving much more detail)